# Lighttpd + PHP permission problems on Fedora

Tags: linux, php, lighttpd, fastcgi

I'm trying to set up a Lighttpd webserver with PHP support. I have basically followed the instructions in [this article](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-lighttpd-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-16-p2), but after restarting the server (though I did not receive an error message and `systemctl status lighttpd.service` claims it's running), the server is not responding.

In `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log` it says

```
(mod_fastcgi.c.978) bind failed for: unix:/var/lib/lighttpd/sockets/php-fastcgi-1.socket-0 Permission denied
```

Which is, itself a straight forward message, apparently the server is lacking the rights to access the `var/lib/lighttpd/sockets` directory. However, I did change the ownership of the directory (recursively) to `lighttpd:lighttpd` and `ls -al /var/lib/lighttpd` gives me this:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  3 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Mar 13 17:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 42 root     root     4096 Mar 13 17:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Mar 13 17:12 sockets
```

So it looks like that worked and the server should have all the necessary permissions. Is there something here I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an SELinux issue. You could temporarily disable SELinux and test this theory. Try executing on the command line

```
sudo echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

and then restart lighttpd. See if it works. If it doesn't work, it isn't an SELinux issue. Reboot the machine to re-enable SELinux or execute:

```
sudo echo 1 >/selinux/enforce
```

If it does fix it, you can disable SELinux or set it to permissive to solve the issue permanently like so:

Edit `/etc/selinux/config` and set

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

and then reboot. Do not set SELinux to disabled as this might cause trouble when you wish to re-activate SELinux later.

Comment: @nijansen You're very welcome!